# Bluez 5 profile interface in python

Tags: python, dbus, bluez

In the Bluez5 sample, test-profile, there is a block of python code of this:

```
class Profile(dbus.service.Object):
    fd = -1

    @dbus.service.method("org.bluez.Profile1",
                    in_signature="", out_signature="")
    def Cancel(self):
        print("Cancel")


    @dbus.service.method("org.bluez.Profile1",
                in_signature="oha{sv}", out_signature="")
    def NewConnection(self, path, fd, properties):
        self.fd = fd.take()
        print("NewConnection(%s, %d)" % (path, self.fd))
        for key in properties.keys():
            if key == "Version" or key == "Features":
                print("  %s = 0x%04x" % (key, properties[key]))
            else:
                print("  %s = %s" % (key, properties[key]))
```

I am new to Python and Bluez, so here are the questions:

#### Question 1

What is the type of fd? Is it `int` for file descriptor? What does it mean `fd.take()`? Can type of int have methods?

#### Question 2

Cancel method is not defined in bluez 5 interface file. Which one is correct?

```
void Release() [noreply]

void NewConnection(object device, fd, dict fd_properties)

void RequestDisconnection(object device)
```